# Symfony 2.3 pass custom data to entity form, using choice or other type

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, formbuilder

**SETUP:**

- Main entity with a related entity with ManyToOne relation.
- Main entity has a formType with the related entity added.
- The related entity is a big object with a lot of fields and related objects, and very slow to get.

> ```
> public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
> {
>   $builder
>       ->add('relatedEntity', 'entity', array(
>           'class' => 'ProjectName\RelatedEntityBundle\Entity\RelatedEntity',
>           'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
>                   $queryBuilder = $er->createQueryBuilder('relatedEntity');
>                   $queryBuilder->resetDQLPart('select');
>                   $queryBuilder->resetDQLPart('from');
>                   $queryBuilder->select('relatedEntity')
>                       ->distinct(true)
>                       ->from('ProjectNameRelatedEntityBundle:RelatedEntity', 'relatedEntity');
>                   return $queryBuilder;
>               },
>        ....
>        ....
> }
> ```

**Template:**
(relateEntity has a `__toString()` function defined to show its name).

> ```
> {{ form_label(form.relatedEntity) }}
> {{ form_widget(form.relatedEntity) }}
> {{ form_errors(form.relatedEntity) }}
> ```

**QUESTIONS:**

1. The Main entity as shown above, will get all objects and pass them
   to the template. It works perfectly but it is very slow since the
   related entity objects are big and the query may take more 10
   seconds to finish hydrating all the object data.
2. **How could I select only some fields from my related entity and show them in the template without getting all objects hydrated?**
3. Is it possible to use the choice option or another type instead of
   the default `entity` type to get only some fields of the related
   entity and show them in the template?
4. How could I build a custom query hydrated as a simple array of key value, and pass that array to the formType, to the queryBuilder of my related entity field?
5. Finally, in case its not possible to get only some fields to be
   shown in the template,  should I avoid symfony 2 forms and make a
   custom management of the related entity?

**TESTS:**
I cant seem to build the form with the [choice type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) by passing just an array to show a selectBox with the id and name of my related entity in the template. I always get the same error, asking me to insert an array of entity objects in that choiceS option.

Lets look at some examples at the formType, buildForm function of the main entity:

- **WORKS**, default Symfony 2 generated code with null type:

> ->add('relatedEntity', null, array('label'=> 'relatedEntity'))

- **WORKS**, with 'entity' type and a simple queryBuilder:

> ```
> ->add('relatedEntity', 'entity', array(
>   'class' => 'ProjectName\RelatedEntityBundle\Entity\RelatedEntity',
>   'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
>           $queryBuilder = $er->createQueryBuilder('relatedEntity');
>           $queryBuilder->resetDQLPart('select');
>           $queryBuilder->resetDQLPart('from');
>           $queryBuilder->select('relatedEntity')
>               ->from('ProjectNameRelatedEntityBundle:RelatedEntity', 'relatedEntity');
>           return $queryBuilder;
>       },
>   'property' => 'descripcion'
> ))
> ```

- **DOESNT WORK** with 'choice' type, with 'choices' option passing an array of values:

> $arrayValues = array('1'=>'name1', '2'=>'name2', '3'=>'name3');
>
> ```
>     ->add('relatedEntity', 'choice', array(
>         'choices' => $arrayValues,
>         'multiple' => false,
>         'label'=> 'relatedEntity'
>     ))
> ```

- **DOESNT WORK** with 'entity' type, with 'choices' option passing an array of values:

> $arrayValues = array('1'=>'name1', '2'=>'name2', '3'=>'name3');
>
> ```
>     ->add('relatedEntity', 'entity', array(
>         'class' => 'ProjectName\RelatedEntityBundle\Entity\RelatedEntity',
>         'choices' => $arrayValues ,
>         'multiple' => false,
>         'label'=> 'relatedEntity'
>     ))
> ```

I have also tested trying to hack the choices input requeriment by building an array of objets of my related entity, but it asks me to persists those entities before being sent to the choice type.

Comment: Have you tried using a DataTransformer? I assume the problem is your Entity, which expects relatedEntity to be an Entity (not a string, i.e. _name_). In order for this to work, you have to reverseTransform your selected value, e.g. `1` when you chose _name1_ into an Entity. The cookbook-entry on DataTransformers (under Forms) should make it clear.

Comment: Ty mahok. As you said it could be issue, however transforming the values back into objects will be a very slow way since I just need to show a selectBox with a value and name in the final form. Thats why I wanted to avoid using the related entity object, and passing only a string in the choice option. I dont really know if there is another way of doing it without having to deal with objects when there are related entities involved. I will clarify a bit more the reasons of the original question in my post to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your form element which requires its content to be an entity, which is an instance of class `ProjectName\RelatedEntityBundle\Entity\RelatedEntity`, but you pass an array as choices:

```
$arrayValues = array(
    '1'=>'name1',
    '2'=>'name2',
    '3'=>'name3'
);
```

On the other hand, when you use a choice-element and add the array, your form element will return a string, whereas your entity requires `relatedEntity` to be an instance of the above mentioned class.

Either way, you have to ensure the data you add or retrieve from the element matches your requirements.

What you can do, is make it a `choice`-element and remove the class-restriction (as you have tried). Then, to ensure it will return an entity-instance rather than a string you can use [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html). You could use `FormEvents::SUBMIT` or `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` to check which entity name was selected and perform a query to fetch the corresponding entity, e.g. something like:

```
$objectRepository->findEntityBy(array('name' => $name));
```

Comment: This is the best approach to solve the problem. At first I though to inyect the entity object in the submitted request, but its not a very good way of handling it. Form events are nice and smart way of doing it, thank you so much :) I will report back with a small example once I get it working with this solution.